# Make Firefox Open a Webpage using C++

Tags: c++, firefox, browser

I just studied the basics of C++ and am trying to make a simple program right now.

I'm trying to make Firefox open a specific webpage. Firefox isn't the default browser, but it is the only browser that's going to be able to run my file. I'm using Windows 7 by the way. I'm ok with OS-dependent codes, as long as the OS we're talking about is Windows. Thanks in advance :)

**Edit:** I meant to ask how to make Firefox (not the default browser) open a specific webpage.

Comment: I don't see a question here

Comment: Sorry. I meant to ask how to make Firefox (not the default browser) open a webpage.

Answer (score 0):

Although I am not sure what you mean by opening a website and what you want to achieve by doing so but there is a very friendly ShellExecute() function in Windows, which will use the user's default web browser to open the URL you specify.

```
#include <shellapi.h>
if (ShellExecute( NULL, TEXT( "open" ), TEXT( "http://www.cplusplus.com/" ), NULL, NULL, 0 ) <= 32)
{
  cout << "I could not open cplusplus.com!\n";
}
```

This snippet would do nothing more than printing

> I could not open C++.

in case it cant connect.
Hope that helps

Comment: The OP said "*not* the default browser."

Answer (score 0):

This works on my PC

```
system("path\\to\\firefox.exe google.com")
```

Comment: I'm able to compile it. But after running the executable file, it just doesn't work. I'm using Dev C++ - the portable version.

Comment: The path\\to\\ in the answer should be replaced by an actual directory. E.g. the following works on my machine, `std::system(R"("C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" google.com)");`